# How to catch a PermissionDenied(403) from Django with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, permission-denied

So im trying to handle a GET request with AJAX instead of Django so I can display a simple pop-up/modal with jQuery when a 403 Forbidden (Given by Django) is raised, however im not sure how to continue right now.

This is my Javasscript that handles the request:

Just gets a button in my html and waits for Click event.

## main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#users_page").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/dashby/users/",
      "beforeSend": function(xhr, settings){
        console.log("Before send");
      },
      "success": function(result){
        window.location.href = "/dashby/users/";
      },
      "error": function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        console.log(error);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

## my view.py for this matter

```
class AllUsersViews(UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    template_name = 'all_users.html'
    raise_exception = True # Raise PermissionDenied(403)

    def test_func(self):
        #Only superusers can access this view.
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return True

    def get(self, request):
        context = {'users': User.objects.all()}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

So right now if im a superuser i do get redirected to the page I want but I want to be able to basically display a message to the user (A pop-up or a modal) saying that they do not have permission if the PermissionForbidden is raised by Django.

Also, I dont want the page to refresh when this happens or that the Chrome Console displays the 403 Forbidden Message.

I dont know if it's actually a lot to ask/ if its long but thanks to any advice/tips in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see HTTP errors in the `error` handler:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        if(xhr.status==403) {
            alert(...);
        }
    }
}
```

You will always see the 403 in the console as that's the HTTP response you are getting from the server.

You can simplify the `test_func` to just:

```
class AllUsersViews(UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    ...

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser

    ...
```

Comment: In a production environment would it be bad practice to leave the 403 in the console or should I go another route to achieve this? Maybe Sending other type of message from Django instead of the 403?

Comment: The only sure way to remove it from console, is not to send it from the server, as many browsers show HTTP errors in any case. If to send 403 or not depends on your application. I think, 401 is more appropriate for missing credentials. 403, in general, means that your client application tries to do access something it should not.

Comment: Allright solved it Overriding UserPassesTestMixin's "handle_no_permission"  and just returning a redirect to the same page but adding a "message" with the django framework.